# Create test with "unscramble the sentence" questions

Tags: gratis, educational, language

I'm looking to create a foreign language test for my students and I want to present them with a sentence with the words in the wrong order. The student will then need to rearrange the words into the correct order. Is there a software that allows that type of question to be created? Which one(s)? I prefer free.

**Notes**:

- It does not have to be a web app.
- It is for adults. I would prefer drag and drop, but the other might work too.

Comment: Does it have to be a web app?

Comment: No it does not.

Comment: The other question is what age group of students - i.e. does it have to be drag and drop or could the students be expected to type in the response?

Comment: It is for adults. I would prefer drag and drop, but the other might work too.